# Connecting to embed yocto using minicom text garbage

Tags: linux, embedded, yocto, minicom

I am trying to connect over serial cable from ubuntu 12.04 to an embedded linux device for which uname -a returns:

```
Linux demosystem 3.10.17-1.0.0_ga+yocto+ga29b925 #1 SMP Mon Jul 6 21:50:27 PDT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I have minicom setup to connect ttyUSB0 from my laptop to a serial port labeled CPU Serial on the device, which corresponds to `ttymxc1`.

Instructions I was given for this connection was:

```
(115200, 8, N, 1, No Flow )
```

Which is how I have minicom setup. (No Hardware and No Software Flow Control)

All other minicom settings were left default.

I have an ssh connection to the embedded device, and when I run minicom on my laptop, I run the command from the device:

```
echo "hello" > /dev/ttymxc1
```

This results in garbage text coming up on minicom, so I know they are connected somehow, but I don't know what setting to check/change in order to be able to get the text correctly transferred.

EDIT:
Also the command on the device: 
    root@demosystem:~# dmesg | grep console 
returns:
    [    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttymxc1,115200 root=/dev/sda1 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait rw video=mxcfb0:dev=adv739x,BT656-NTSC,if=BT656,fbpix=RGB565,bpp=32 video=mxcfb1:off video=mxcfb2:off video=mxcfb3:off cma=384M galcore.gpu3DMinClock=3
[    1.791357] console [ttymxc1] enabled

Comment: Are you getting the same number of characters, like they're a different encoding, or does it look more like garbage (like a protocol mismatch)? I'd verify the baud rate on both sides and try something like `cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | hexdump -C` and compare the output. You may also need to verify you don't need other control lines hooked up on the serial link.

Comment: Did you try turning it off and back on again? I've often had problems like this when connecting the serial port to an embedded device when the embedded device was already powered on. Leaving the serial port connected and rebooting the device would fix it.

Comment: @melds Sorry away from the laptop now but I'm nearly sure the same amount of characters show up each time

Comment: @drewbenn I've tried rebooting but usually I disconnect the port, il give this a try too

Comment: try `echo "hello" > /dev/console` ...

Comment: PS: default baud rate is usually 9600 - maybe try something like `(stty 115200 && echo "hello") < /dev/ttymxc1 > /dev/ttymxc1` ...